# How to fit the dual exponential or double exponential in R language

Tags: r, curve-fitting, exponential

I have some data to fit. The function is like : 
`y = a*exp(b*x) + c*exp(d*x)` ,
where "a", "b" ,"c"  and "d" are the coefficients

I want to use `gnm` package to fit the dual exponential function. However, the result seems not good. 
Is any other package to do this ?

Can Java or other language do it?

`library(gnm);
    data = read.table("F:\\AP\\R\\data.txt", header = T);
    x <- data$X1;
    y <- data$Y1;
    set.seed(1);
    saved.fits <- list();
    for(i in 1:60){
       saved.fits[[i]] <- suppressWarnings(gnm(y ~ Exp(1+x, inst = 1)+         Exp(1+x, inst =2),verbose = FALSE))
    }
    table(round(unlist(sapply(saved.fits, deviance)), 4))`

X1:
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
85
86
87
88
89
90
91
92
93
94
95
96
97
98
99
100
101
102
103
104
105
106
107
108
109
110
111
112
113
114
Y1:
9514.833
9463.002
9386.4277
9320.292
9252.0957
9187.4775
9122.5947
9068.1279
9013.3232
8930.418
8875.416
8789.1973
8727.9355
8649.0547
8600.0693
8529.3359
8490.0801
8421.7842
8371.4688
8303.041
8256.1719
8193.1416
8159.1553
8091.3022
8028.9263
7966.6748
7893.2056
7819.4702
7710.0962
7613.6069
5609.2266
5573.5923
5537.665
5501.6279
5477.5825
5450.0518
5435.9521
5402.5327
5379.1743
5348.1226
5320.5049
5282.2158
5263.5146
5236.125
5216.4038
5188.0493
5170.293
5142.6416
5114.8125
5087.1606
5059.5898
5032.0352
5001.5537
4979.8364
4951.5854
4932.1138
4903.7363
4888.1841
4869.7168
4854.7617

I also have a question about can I use Matlab instead of R in the web server. Because I have to process some electrical signals by methods such as filter, smooth, fitting and so on. But I am afraid that the Matlab liabray will be crashed when the concurrent tasks increase.

Comment: please give us a reproducible example and tell us what specifically what "not good" means.  You can use `nls()` from base R, but you'll need reasonably good starting estimates.

Comment: Also the nls2 package has more options.

Comment: You can also contrusct yourself the L2 cost function and use `optim`. Is it actually what `nls` is supposed to do but `optim` is far more accurate.

Comment: I am sorry for not replying so long. "not good" means the R^2 is smaller than matlab does, so I think the precision of gnm package is not very good.